# emu8086 assembly Int 16 ah=01h, how to empty buffer?

Tags: assembly, dos, emu8086

Im coding a little game with keyboard strokes 'a' and 's', i dont wanna have a wait in my loop, so i tried int 16h, ah=01h. when i press key 'a' it acts as if key was stuck, how to empty/flush buffer after key is pressed ?

```
mov ah,01h
int 16h
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you know there's a keypress waiting to be read with int16 function 1, just get the key using function 0:

```
mov ah, 1   ; peek
int 16h
jz  NoKey
mov ah, 0   ; get
int 16h
```

Comment: awesome, that works good, i've spent the half day on this, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to clear the buffer you can use this:

```
proc ClearBuffKB
      push ax
@@CheckBuffer:
      mov ah ,1
      int 16h
      jz @@return 
      mov ah ,0
      int 16h
      jmp @@CheckBuffer
@@return:
      pop ax
      ret
endp ClearBuffKB
```